# Difference between heritability on the scale of liability versus the scale of observation

Tags: genetics, evolution, bioinformatics, human-genetics, theoretical-biology

I was reading a paper on disease heritability ("Estimating Missing Heritability for Disease from Genome-wide Association Studies") and it struck me that I don't have a great understanding of the differences between heritability on the liability scale and the observed scale. The main thing that I've read about is how the liability scale operates on an assumption of normality (since traits are treated as being continuous) making it unimodal and only appropriate for multifactorial disease. However, I'm not sure if I've caught on to the full extent of the difference.

Any input would be appreciated, even if it's just pushing me in the direction of a useful resource :)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Does [this page from our sister Bioinformatics site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/6868/4941) help? OR maybe [this page](https://www.nealelab.is/blog/2017/9/13/heritability-201-types-of-heritability-and-how-we-estimate-it)?